# Cybersource payer authentication issue

Tags: php, payment-gateway, omnipay, 3d-secure

Iam integrating cybersource payment gateway. I have used omnipay cybersource package for the same, Now I want to enable 3d security aka payer authentication but not able to figure out how and from where can I get any code reference and endpoints for the same.

All I need is a sample code from where I can refer the 3d security implementations and the endpoints.

Comment: It is a PITA when we found out that the omnipay does not support 3D

Answer (score 1):

The endpoints it is the same for all service within Cybersource API, which are:
- Production: https://ics2ws.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/
- Test: https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/

Example of requests and reply can be found here: http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Payer_Authentication_SO_API/Payer_Authentication_SO_API.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete source code and best fit for your requirement.

Use http://localhost:8080/sa-sop

This code will authorize the user if the card is 3D and will redirect to the override_page_response url defined in the hidden field inside the payment-form.php.

Download the source code from Github

https://github.com/e-payment/cybersource-secure-acceptance/tree/master/php

Comment: I am also integration silent order post api and stuck at 3D. I will try this solution. Is this solution work for dummy visa card also?

Comment: @MarkWaugh Yes, it work for dummy visa card {both 3D and Non-3D}, if you are testing on a sandbox account.